# Asterisk Readout Decimal

Tags: command, asterisk, voip, ivr, pbx

I am attempting to have asterisk readout a number using the SayNumber() command. However, if that number is a decimal, asterisk refuses to read it. Basically, asterisk will not read say 77.77 0r 83.23, but will read other whole number values like 20 or 60.Is there a function to read decimal numbers specifically?

PS. Or is there a way to truncate the decimal, leaving the whole number part only?

Answer (score 0):

You have split your value to 2 values A.B, and do SayNumber(A) +Streamfile(dot)+SayNumber B

Or you can check a2billing.org or any other opensource billing code, it already have function to say number.

Other option - hire developer to do for you application.

Sorry, asterisk is pbx, it have only needed functions.